# How to run mysql insert without duplicates in java

Tags: java, mysql, insert

I have a method which insert a record to mysql database as bellow,

```
public boolean addOrganization(OrganizationDTO organizationDTO) {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        String insertOrganizationSQL = "INSERT INTO organizations (org_id, org_name) VALUES(?, ?)";
        con = JDBCConnectionPool.getInstance().checkOut();
        PreparedStatement insertOrgPS = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(insertOrganizationSQL);
        insertOrgPS.setString(1, organizationDTO.getOrg_id());
        insertOrgPS.execute();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JDBCConnectionPool.getInstance().checkIn(con);
        logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        JDBCConnectionPool.getInstance().checkIn(con);
    }
}
```

database table,

```
CREATE TABLE `organizations` (
  `org_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `org_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sys_dat_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`org_id`)
)
```

what I need is, when I insert a new record if, that is a duplicate exit the method without trying to insert and inform the user that it is a duplicate record. Is it possible to do without writing another method to search the record before inserting?

Comment: You can do an INSERT IGNORE and then check how many rows were affectd. If it's zero, it was a duplicate.

Comment: Add a unique key to the appropriate columns?

Comment: I found a solution for my problem from [this][1] qestion


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 0):

I would add a UNIQUE constraint to your table. For example, if org_name needs to be unique:

```
ALTER TABLE organizations ADD UNIQUE (org_name);
```

Then observe what's returned when you try to insert a duplicate record through Java. Add code to check for this, and if it occurs, display the message to your user.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) is the reference documentation for ALTER TABLE.

Answer (score 0):

Thats right, Alter table will surely help.

In your case, let say, both org_id and org_name is there, I would add unique in both, just avoid any confusion later.